# Opera OL bad text align with justify

Tags: html-lists, opera

I'm having a problem with **justify alignment** of **list items** (`<li>`) in an ordered list (`<ol>`) in **Opera**. There are different spacings in front of the lines.

Opera version:

- Version: 11.62
- Build: 1347
- Platform: Win32
- System: Windows 7

Screenshots:

[image: Opera 11.62 (Build 1347), Windows 7 - ordered list indentation problem]

[image: Opera 11.62 (Build 1347), Windows 7 - ordered list indentation problem]
(reproduced at jsfiddle.com)

Test code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ySmJZ/

```
ol {
  list-style: decimal;
  margin: 16px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: What version of Opera on what OS? Looks fine on my V11.50 Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I made a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/1d7sm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug in Opera (CORE-41499). There isn't really a workaround, except to avoid using `text-align:justify.`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known bug in Opera (even in `12.01 (x86)`), but there IS a workaround, written by *deathshadow* here:
http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1424852&t=1347118644&page=1#comment12696422

Citing:

> *"One workaround (until/if they fix it) is an extra SPAN or DIV inside the LI wrapping all the content set to `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;`"*

I tried it, and it really works (at least in Opera 12.01 (x86)):

http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/ySmJZ/10/

### BEFORE

[image: Opera bug with ordered lists (<ol>) and text-align:justify;]

### AFTER

[image: Opera bug with ordered lists (<ol>) and text-align:justify; WORKAROUND]