# Weird behaviour when highlighting list items using opera

Tags: css, cross-browser, opera

When I highlight my list items using the mouse, parts of my text just disappear or get moves towards the left side. This sometimes also happens when I click or just move the mouse over without clicking or highlighting.
It only happen with list items, I used Joomla to make my website.

I tested this with Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera, Opera is the only one that has this behavior.

I suppose this has something to do with my CSS?!?!?

Comment: Was this written in Microsoft Word or something? FrontPage? Something absolutely awful?

Comment: @setek I used Joomla for the whole thing, so the editor was just the standard TinyMCE. Although, now that you say it, what I did do is copy the text into Joomla's editor from word. I don't see how this should affect the outcome though...

Comment: Because when you paste from Word into any WYSIWYG editor, it tries to carry across styling. And it pretty much always does a terrible job of it. When I only copy the source and CSS across into a fiddle, your problem does not exist in Opera 12 anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/9Af3T/

Comment: @setek I retyped one of the lists bullets in the editor, the HTML of that looked exactly the same as before. I tried making just a `<ul><li>my list</li></ul>`list structure and I still get the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Opera Presto (12.x and earlier) that occurs when you try to apply `text-align: justify` styles to `li` items. Either don't try to justify the list item content, or use the workaround specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332174/983430), i.e. instead of this:

```
<li>list item text</li>
```

you would wrap the text in a `span` or `div`, something like this:

```
<li>
  <span class="listItemContent">list item text</span>
</li>
```

and define your `listItemContent` class (or whatever you want to call it) as:

```css
.listItemContent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

That should do the trick (I just tried it in Dragonfly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site that explains how you can specify certain CSS Settings for different browsers.

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

However, I dont see a list on the Bottom of your page. I use Chrome and the list on your Home Page does not get highlighted at all. Is this the part you are talking about?

Maybe you can give us a little bit more code here.

Comment: I am refering to the bullet list at the end of the text. The problem is not that it gets highlighted, but rather that the formatting changes when I highlight it.

Comment: I don't want to change anything, the text is moving and randomly formating when I highlight it just by clicking and dragging the mouse along. By highlighting the text I just mean selecting it, exactly the same thing you do before you can copy a selected text.